# Why can't I use action selectors with descendant elements

Tags: css, google-chrome

Here is a simple HTML with what I thought would be simple CSS (note that two items are links and two are not):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      li.menu:hover {
        background-color: #0ff;
      }

      li.menu a {
        background-color: #0f0;
      }

      li.menu a:hover {
        background-color: #00f;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li class="menu"><a>item1</a></li>
      <li class="menu"><a>item2</a></li>
      <li class="menu">item3</li>
      <li class="menu">item4</li>
    <ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, in Firefox, this works as I expected, but in Chrome (v24) it doesn't.

I would expect item1 and item2 to have `#0f0` (green) color when not hovered above, and `#00f` (blue) color when hovered. But they are always green (in Chrome)! So why `:hover` works for item3 and item4, but not for item1 and item2?

Is there a way which will also work in Chrome, and still be this simple?

Comment: Seems to be working in FF

Comment: @KevinBowersox - You are right. Editing question to point out it is only about Chrome. Also willmake an example in one file, for easier testing... Really weird that Chrome doesn't like this.

Comment: Seems to be working both in FF and Chrome v24 over here ([example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iydrz)).

Comment: @RubenInfante ugh! use jsfiddle man! this codepen is sooo slow

Comment: @abbood I normally use jsfiddle, but the service was down when I was writing my comment. Honestly, I think having options and multiple services is a good thing. Also, it is not any slower than jsfiddle on my machine.

Comment: For me it doesn't work in Chrome. It is really weird! For record, I am now on Windows, but what does that matter? I opened the file both as file://... and through Apache as http://...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define `li:hover a:hover` and it should work.